# TWIG, Multidimensional array and Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array, twig

Using a JSON API feed, I'm getting this using curl and then json_decode which if I'm correct gives me an array. I'm able to display specific data from the array using this `$successes = $data2['Data']['0']['OID'];`.

I'm wanting to extract the OID for each of the data entries on the API, so I end up with a list displaying just all the OID's. My thinking was to use `$first_names = array_column($data2, 'OID');` and then use print_r, but I can't seem to work out how you would then display this correctly using twig?

```
$url2 = 'https://home-api.letmc.com/v2/tier3/letmcletting/property/properties/'.$letmc_property_id.'/photos?offset=0&count=1000&api_key='.$letmc_apikey.''; 
        $ch2 = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);    
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output2 = curl_exec($ch2);
        curl_close($ch2);
        $data2 = json_decode($output2, true);

        $successes = $data2['Data']['0']['OID'];

        $this->_app->render('tennant/tennant-my-property.twig', [
            "theOIDs" => $successes,
        ]);
```

Example of API feed

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "OID": "0908-703e-0fe1-235c",
      "ETag": "0908-703e-0fe1-235c-0",
      "Name": "",
      "FileName": "white lounge.jpg",
      "InspectionItem": "0000-0000-0000-0000",
      "InterimInspection": "0000-0000-0000-0000",
      "InventoryItem": "0000-0000-0000-0000",
      "Property": "0907-f421-2742-7351",
      "Room": "0000-0000-0000-0000",
      "PhotoNumber": 3
    },
    {
      "OID": "0908-8a9b-c1f9-5219",
      "ETag": "0908-8a9b-c1f9-5219-0",
      "Name": "",
      "FileName": "Large kitchen with island.jpg",
      "InspectionItem": "0000-0000-0000-0000",
      "InterimInspection": "0000-0000-0000-0000",
      "InventoryItem": "0000-0000-0000-0000",
      "Property": "0907-f421-2742-7351",
      "Room": "0000-0000-0000-0000",
      "PhotoNumber": 2
    }
  ],
  "Count": 2
}
```

Any help or ideas would be great!

UPDATE
I'm also able to get a specific entry from the array using twig like this `{{ theOIDs['Data'][0]['OID'] }}` if I change theOIDs to $data2. Is there a way for me to foreach using twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this loop:

```
<ul>
    {% for elem in Data %}
        <li>{{ elem.OID}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

A working example in this [twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/5h62l6).

Hope this help